# Using PassportJS's oAuth2 to access Gmail's API, not returning accesstoken, refreshtoken or profile

Tags: javascript, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, passport.js

I'm using PassportJS on top of Node to authorise my app to send/receive emails via Gmail.

I'm using [Passport's oAuth2 strategy, docs are here](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-oauth2).

I'm quite confused as to how the success callback functions work with Passport, and I'm currently not getting the data I need (a user profile, an access token and a refresh token).

My code:

```
 app.get('/auth/gmail',
      passport.authenticate('oauth2',{ scope : ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me'],
                                  accessType: 'offline', approvalPrompt: 'force' }));

 passport.use(new OAuth2Strategy({
    authorizationURL: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
    tokenURL: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
    clientID: configAuth.googleAuth.clientID,
    clientSecret: configAuth.googleAuth.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: configAuth.googleAuth.callback2
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    process.nextTick(function() {

        console.log("Token is ");
        console.log(util.inspect(accessToken, false, null));

        console.log("Refresh is ");
        console.log(util.inspect(refreshToken, false, null));

        console.log("Profile is ");
        console.log(util.inspect(profile, false, null));
```

etc.

This gives me a response of:

```
Token is 
'{access token}'
Refresh is 
undefined
Profile is
{}
```

Perhaps I don't understand callback functions correctly, but when my function is:

```
 function(req, token, refreshToken, profile, done) {}
```

my response is:

```
Token is 
undefined
Refresh is 
{ access_token: '{an access token}',
  token_type: 'Bearer',
  expires_in: 3599,
  id_token:'{a really long string}' }
Profile is
{}
```

Any ideas on what's going on here? The `Passport-oAuth2` documentation is really lacking in this regard...

Comment: Are Google+ API enable in Google Developers Console for your project?

Comment: Yes. I eventually got this working via using Passport's `Google-oAuth2` strategy. I was under the assumption that Gmail's oAuth system was different to Google+'s, but it can all work together if you just add in the right scope and permissions (at least, I think it can, up to that bit now!)

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation and code (result is null) you need to implement this method yourself, or use an existing strategy specific to Google:

```
/**
 * Retrieve user profile from service provider.
 *
 * OAuth 2.0-based authentication strategies can overrride this function in
 * order to load the user's profile from the service provider.  This assists
 * applications (and users of those applications) in the initial registration
 * process by automatically submitting required information.
 *
 * @param {String} accessToken
 * @param {Function} done
 * @api protected
 */
OAuth2Strategy.prototype.userProfile = function(accessToken, done) {
  return done(null, {});
};
```

**Upd**: You can use this OAuth2 strategy: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth